# Execute a "prepared" math operation in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-4.2

I want to to math operations with some kind of prepared formula that would look like `tan(%f)*1000` or `%f+%f` where the %f has to be replaced by an argument.

Is there a function in Objective-C that I can pass the format of my formula and the required numbers to execute this prepared operation?

I hope the problem is described understandable, if not, leave a comment.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:** Thanks for your answers so far, but I'm looking for something more dynamic. The block and inline function is great, but to static. I also understand that this may be something hard to achieve out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in DDMathParser, [found here](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser). I believe it will do everything you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing that would do it this way, however what you could do is rewrite your "format" into a function, and just pass the arguments it needs to have, much faster and much easier.

```
inline float add(float p_x,float p_y)
{ return p_x+p_y; }
```

inline is a compiler feature that you can use to speed things up. It will replace the function call with the code it executes when you compile. This will result in a lager binary though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, Objective-C Blocks are great for this.

```
typedef double (^CalcBlock)(double);
CalcBlock myBlock = ^(double input) {
    return (tan(input) * 1000);
};

NSLog(@"Result: %f", myBlock(M_PI_2));
```

You can pass the block that contains your algorithm to other objects or methods.