# NSString category calculator

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, calculator

I'm trying to find a way to calculate result from NSString.
Is there a simple NSString calculator category?

```
NSString *str = @"10+20/2";
int result = [[str stringByCalculatingResult] intValue];
NSLog (@"result:%i", result);
```

Prefer output:

```
result:20
```

Thank you for solution.

Category:

```
//NSString+Calculator.h
@interface NSString (Calculator)
- (NSString*)stringByCalculatingResult;
@end

//NSString+Calculator.m
@implementation NSString (Calculator)
- (NSString*)stringByCalculatingResult
{
    NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:self];
    NSNumber *value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
    return [value stringValue];
}
@end
```

Comment: what about using NSPredicate like this?


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618005/how-to-convert-string-to-math-equation-in-objective-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to evaluate the string equation in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785873/how-to-evaluate-the-string-equation-in-ios)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Calculating string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072439/objective-c-calculating-string-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at using the `NSExpression` class which can evaluate mathematical expressions for you:

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"10 + 20 / 2"];
id value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [mathematical parser library](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser)